# How to catch any exception (System.Exception) without a warning in F#?

Tags: exception, f#

I tried to catch an Exception but the compiler gives warning: This type test or downcast will always hold

```
let testFail () =
    try
        printfn "Ready for failing..."
        failwith "Fails"
    with
    | :? System.ArgumentException -> ()
    | :? System.Exception -> ()
```

The question is: how to I do it without the warning? (I believe there must be a way to do this, otherwise there should be no warning)

Like C#

```cs
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ready for failing...");
    throw new Exception("Fails");
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Comment: Your C# example causes a warning for anyone using ReSharper or FxCop. [Why?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/06/14/631923.aspx)

Comment: @Joel Mueller, thank you for your article. I don't like to catch general exception either, but sometimes unexpected exception may confuse users.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

C#:

```cs
void testFail()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ready for failing...");
        throw new Exception("Fails");
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

F# equivalent:

```ml
let testFail () =
    try
        printfn "Ready for failing..."
        failwith "Fails"
    with
    | :? System.ArgumentException -> ()
    | _ -> ()
```

---

C#:

```cs
void testFail()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ready for failing...");
        throw new Exception("Fails");
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

F# equivalent:

```ml
let testFail () =
    try
        printfn "Ready for failing..."
        failwith "Fails"
    with
    | :? System.ArgumentException as ex -> ()
    | ex -> ()
```

---

C#:

```cs
void testFail()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ready for failing...");
        throw new Exception("Fails");
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

F# equivalent:

```ml
let testFail () =
    try
        printfn "Ready for failing..."
        failwith "Fails"
    with
    | _ -> ()
```

---

As Joel noted, you would not want to use `catch (Exception)` in C# for the same reason you don't use `| :? System.Exception ->` in F#.

Comment: Thank you. That's very detailed. After reading Joel's comment, I will try to avoid catching general exception. But I guess sometimes it may be necessary to fail gracefully... (At least give error messages in user-friendly way)

Comment: @LLS : It's not that catching the base `Exception` type is necessarily a problem, it's that `catch(Exception){}` and `catch{}` have identical semantics, so the former is redundant and produces a warning. If you _name_ the exception object, `catch(Exception ex){}`, there's no warning.

Answer (score 7):

```
try 
  .. code ..
with
  | _ as e ->
```

Comment: I did not know you could alias the wildcard match like that. That's really handy (and not just for exception handling)

Comment: The `_` is really redundant, and actually this code undermines the purpose of the `_` variable

`| _ as e -> (...)`

does nothing different from 

`| e -> (..) `

any var without guard clause in a pattern matching statement is a catch all, naming the variable `_` simply states that you don't care about the value. Aliasing the `_` kind of undermines the `_` in the first place.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The lecture in the currently-accepted answer is unnecessary and unhelpful. I just want to turn 2 exceptions' messages into a Result of string error in my hackathon project