# f# handling exceptions for multiple exception types

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am trying to catch exceptions based on exception type like in c#, but I am getting compiler error when I do the following
`This type test or downcast will always`  at line `| :? System.Exception as genericException ->`
Can you not have multiple "catch" blocks in F#?

```
try
    ......
with
| :? System.AggregateException as aggregateException ->
   for innerException in aggregateException.InnerExceptions do
                log message
| :? System.Exception as genericException ->
           log message
```

Comment: I don't think you need the explicit type test, the last clause can just be `| genericException -> log message`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to catch any exception (System.Exception) without a warning in F#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616646/how-to-catch-any-exception-system-exception-without-a-warning-in-f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `:? System.Exception as` is redundant, and the code can be reduced to the following:

```
try
    // ...
with
| :? System.AggregateException as aggregateException ->
    for innerException in aggregateException.InnerExceptions do
        log message
| genericException -> log message
```

See this answer for further examples: [How to catch any exception (System.Exception) without a warning in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6616790/636019)